# Update Amazon EC2 Instance From Previous Generation to Latest

Tags: amazon-ec2, server

My client has an Amazon EC2 instance with instance type m1.medium. Now he wants to change the instance type to reduce costs. I found that t2.micro is more cost effective and suitable for the projects that run under it. In order to change the instance type, I stopped the instance from the AWS Console, then I tried to change it from Action>Instance Settings>Change Instance Type. But there is no option in the dropdown for t2.micro. I know that m1.medium is the previous generation instance type and that t2.micro is latest generation. Is that why it's not showing up? How can I solve this?

Comment: Is the virtualization type of the current instance (shown in the console) "paravirtual?" Does it have a 32-bit or 64-bit processor?

Comment: Yes, its "paravirtual" and It has 64 bit processor

Answer (score 2):

m1.medium (and m1 family) supports only paravirtual AMIs. t2 family on the other hand supports only HVM AMI. That is more likely the reason why it does not allow to change the instance type.

Refer to the section "Compatibility for Resizing Instances" at http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-instance-resize.html